# взрыв объекта это отдельный объект или часть взрываемого?

Tags: ооп, разработка-игр

как правильно будет сделать взрыв объекта в игре, отдельным объектом или частью взрываемого?

Comment: Какая именно часть взрыва вас интересует, как сделать и где хранить  - разбитие объекта на части/осколки, или спецэффекты (частицы/звук/итп)?

Comment: да, разбитие обьекта, осколки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если взрыв может быть без объекта, то надо делать взрыв как отдельный объект.

Если взрыв **всегда** связан с объектом, то можно сделать взрыв частью объекта.

Если объекты разные, а взрыв всегда один, то взрыв нужно делать базовым классом объекта.

Но, исходя из моего опыта, надо делать взрыв отдельным объектом.

Так будет проще перепроектировать, если вдруг какие-то новые вводные появятся.

Например, если понадобится просто взрыв без объекта, как при обстреле по площадям.

Или понадобятся разные взрывы, с дымом, без дыма, с осколками, без осколков.

Собственная иерархия взрывов, отделенная от иерархии объектов, проще поддерживается и гибче настраивается.